# Facebook Javascript Inviting Friends

Tags: javascript, facebook

Basically, I have this piece of Javascript below:

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('uiButton _1sm'); 
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

The user simply loads up a Facebook page, clicks on the 'See All' under "Invite Your Friends to Like This Page", scroll all the way down, then paste the above code into the console.

I was wondering if there's any way to modify this script to ensure that it automatically scrolls down to the bottom of the 'Friends List' before it starts inviting?

And maybe even a 0.3 second delay between each invite?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll down using `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` before inviting all the the friends. The `scrollTo()` method scrolls the document to specified coordinates. So as you call this, the document will automatically scroll until it reaches the end. You need to use `setInterval()` to call this, and as soon as the end is reached you would need to `clearInterval()`.

Have a look at my chrome extension on Github for inviting all friends to like any Facebook page [here](https://github.com/aakash-cr7/invitify) (Github). Also you can download my chrome extension from the [google chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/invitify/boldhogipkbpcaleacilidonmlchcnbh).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('headerTextLink')[0].click(); //Open Layer
window.setTimeout( function(){ //Timeout for 3 seconds
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('uiButton _1sm'); 
  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
    inputs[i].click(); 
  }
}, 3000);
```

I hope, this is only for you. It's a dirty trick for inviting all friends at once.
You should think about whom you are sending an invitation. Otherwise it is spam.

Comment: Personal use and testing really, thanks. But I do also have a Facebook account just for admining pages, all of the friends on there are fans, so I don't see an issue lol

Comment: This script doesn't scroll

Answer (score 0):

Well , let this message. Here in this article I will share some way invite all friends to your Facebook fan page a click . We just need a simple script that automatically invite all your friends by clicking on a button to use . So , follow these simple steps and enjoy ..

1. Open your Facebook page , where you want to invite your friends.
2. Now simply navigate to the public to build > Invite option.
3. Now , a dialog box will be the option to invite all your friends
   name.
4. Press F12 to open inspect element tab.
5. Go to the Console, tab and copy and paste the following script.

   ```
   var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('uiButton _1sm');
   for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
   {
       inputs[i].click();
   }
   ```
6. After the paste code above in the list of the console, then hit enter and see the magic ! all your friends will be invited to your Facebook page.